# Clash Royale: What is the difference between placing a card in the bottom-side corner vs behind the king tower?

Tags: clash-royale

Usually, when players are about to reach their max elixir, they place down a troop (i.e. knight, giant) in the back, either behind the king tower or in the bottom corner to the side.

I understand this would make a difference for flying cards like Lava Hound, but what is the difference besides one route being faster than the other? How to pro players determine which option is better?